# Why doesn't UIScrollView/UITableview respond to taps on the status bar, and scroll to the top?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

When I tap on the status bar, the `UIScrollView` in my app does not respond and scroll to the top. Nothing happens. What could cause the `UIScrollView` to ignore taps on the status bar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can occur when there are multiple instances of `UIScrollView` (or a subclass of `UIScrollView`, such as `UITableView`) with the `scrollsToTop` property set to `YES` on the same view, such as when a `UIScrollView` is added as a subview to a `UIScrollView`. Make sure that the `scrollsToTop` property of only one scroll view is set to `YES`. The correct `UIScrollView` should respond to tap events on the status bar after.

Comment: It is actually the case that if there is more than one `UIScrollView` with `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` on screen at any time, none of them will scroll to top via the status bar, regardless of their relative positions in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

Like Jack said, you can only have one subclass of `UIScrollView` (usually the table view) that has the `scrollsToTop` property set to `YES`. Likely you have others, typically `UITextView` in your view. Just set their `scrollsToTop` property to `NO` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Also check `scrollsToTop` in all container views if you have ones.