# Scroll to top TableView by tapping status bar not work (with many subviews) SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, statusbar

I have many views and for each views, many subviews.
I tried to specify for each subviews

```
scrollsToTop = false
```

but my `TableView` doesn't scroll to top when I press the status bar. 
I suppose I missed some views...

[image: SB]

I know there is a similar post but it doesn't answer ([UITableView scroll to top when tapping status bar at top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951357/uitableview-scroll-to-top-when-tapping-status-bar-at-top-of-the-screen))

So I decided to implement this function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {   

    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkForScrollViewInView(self.view)

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.scrollsToTop = true
}

func checkForScrollViewInView(view:UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UITextView) {
            (subview as! UITextView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
            (subview as! UIScrollView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UITableView) {
            (subview as! UITableView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
            self.checkForScrollViewInView(subview)
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work too. I don't know what I miss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found why my tableview wouldn't scroll!

I called my checkForScrollViewInView() function only in the viewDidLoad of my table view's view controller. In order to disable scrollToTop for every child views.

But I forgot that I had another "active" view controller... In my app I have a left menu which opens to swipe. Calling checkForScrollViewInView() in the left menu's view controller solves my issue.

```
func checkForScrollViewInView(view:UIView) {

    for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UITextView) {
            (subview as! UITextView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
            (subview as! UIScrollView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if subview.isKindOfClass(UITableView) {
            (subview as! UITableView).scrollsToTop = false
        }

        if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
            self.checkForScrollViewInView(subview)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may stuggle with 2 problems:

1. You have more than one instance of `UIScrollView`. You should disable `scrollsToTop` (eg. `self.collectionView?.scrollsToTop = false` in `viewDidLoad`) for the parent `UIScrollView` or objects that inherit from it (like `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`).

From Apple `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_:)`

> If the delegate doesn’t implement this method, true is assumed. For the scroll-to-top gesture (a tap on the status bar) to be effective, the scrollsToTop property of the UIScrollView must be set to YES.

2. If your hierarchy is highly customized method `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop` won't be called. You should check why does happen. Otherwise you will have to some dirty work: add some gestures and handle them.

Interesting links:

[Scroll to top of UITableView by tapping status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165913/scroll-to-top-of-uitableview-by-tapping-status-bar)

[Why doesn't UIScrollView/UITableview respond to taps on the status bar, and scroll to the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370512/why-doesnt-uiscrollview-uitableview-respond-to-taps-on-the-status-bar-and-scro)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewShouldScrollToTop: